# Add a button/link for canceling a question edit (discarding change)

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design

When editing my own question, sometimes I want to discard the change. This can be done by navigating away, but ideally there should be a place within the browseable area (e.g. a button or link near the "Save Edits" button) that allows me to go back to the original question thus discarding my changes.

In Wikipedia for example, at the bottom of the editing page there is a small "Cancel" link next to the big "Save Page" button.

I tagged this a "bug" because it seems to be a missing feature rather than a feature request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [has been declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32277/add-a-cancel-button-when-editing-an-answer/32283#32283) in the past on our sister meta-site, [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com):

> Adding a "cancel" button means there's some percent chance people will accidentally click on it and lose their changes.
>
> It's another item on the page that [Makes You Think](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000377.html).
>
> Compare with the back button, and I can't see any reason to make this change.

I would agree with that: the back button accomplishes the same thing.